# get notification when Red Hat releases update/patch for $PACKAGE

Tags: rhel, package-management, notifications

I wish to get email notifications when RedHat releases an update/patch for only certain packages.

```
# rpm -qa | grep maria
mariadb-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
mariadb-galera-common-5.5.41-2.el7ost.x86_64
mariadb-galera-server-5.5.41-2.el7ost.x86_64
mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
```

Galera is in OpenStack channel. How can I receive an email when MariaDB related packages get released?

We use Satellite snapshots. I need somehow from Redhat to get mails. No systems are patched.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Satellite 5.x and your Satellite runs periodically satellite-sync (highly recommended) then you just go to System Details -> Properties -> Notifications > Check "Receive Notifications of Updates/Errata." And Satellite will send you email automatically.

However it will send you email when any errata is available. You cannot choose your own set of packages.

However - if your problem is need to apply security erratas, I highly recommend you to install yum-cron-security, which automatically install all security erratas for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link it has exactly what you need to start. I have pasted the contents into the answer for easy reading and in case the page changes or moves etc.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/red-hat-centos-fedora-send-package-update-notification-via-email/

> How do I send Automatic Email Notification under RHEL v4/5, CentOS,
>   Red Hat and Fedora Linux, when security & package updates available?
>   How do I force yum to send an email when upgrades available?
>
> RHEL / Fedora / CentOS has yum-updatesd, which provides notification
>   of updates which are available to be applied to your system. This
>   notification can be done either via syslog, email or over dbus.
>   Configuration is done via the /etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf file.
>
> Open /etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf file, enter:

```
# vi /etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf
```

> Setup variables as follows:

```
emit_via = email
# who to send the email to:
email_to = admin@example.com
# who send the notifications
email_from = adm@staff.example.com
```

> Here is complete working config file:

```
# how often to check for new updates (in seconds)
run_interval = 3600
# how often to allow checking on request (in seconds)
updaterefresh = 600

# how to send notifications (valid: dbus, email, syslog)
emit_via = email
# who to send the email
email_to = admin@example.com

# who send the notifications
email_from = adm@staff.example.com
#
# should we listen via dbus to give out update information/check for
# new updates
dbus_listener = yes

# automatically install updates
do_update = no
# automatically download updates
do_download = no
# automatically download deps of updates
do_download_deps = no
```

> Hi, This is the automatic update system on node02.nixcraft.co.in.
>   There are 2 package updates available. Please run the system updater.
>   Packages available for update:
>       device-mapper-multipath
>       kpartx Thank You, Your Computer

Comment: this don't work in our environment. We use Satellite Snapshots.

Comment: can you clarify for me what do you mean by satellite snapshots...?

Comment: why would someone down vote this if there was no dialogue ... this is why some people do not get help or help others...

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, either, Satellite just presented to `yum` as a repo anyways.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible; once the patch completed, we got email notifications on Redhat satellite server.